# Macbook Big Sur screen flickering (briefly goes black then returns to normal)

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur, screen

I just upgraded to Big Sur 11.4 from Catalina 10.15 on my MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). It completed without error.

Everything is fine, except...

Randomly, approx once per hour, but can be as little as a couple of minutes apart, the entire screen goes black for about 1/2 second, then it returns to normal.

This never happened before the upgrade.

Any ideas on how to stop this behaviour?

Comment: Try safe mode (hold shift at start till you see the Apple logo). SMC reset and PRAM/NVRAM resets might be worth a shot as they don't take much time and can't do any harm. Edit your question with the results from the suggestions. I have the same Mac and my upgrade went well. So maybe a search on the Apple forums for other people having similar issues.

Comment: @SteveChambers thanks for the suggestions. I tried each one separately to scientifically determine what fixed it. Unfortunately none of your suggestions made any difference. Disabling True Tone did the trick (see answer).

Comment: My issue was faulty HDMI cable, so you can change and try

Comment: @Arefe my problem was with the laptop’s screen. I don’t actually use a second screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling True Tone fixed the problem.

```
System Preferences > Display > Uncheck "True Tone"
```

---

FYI many posts/blogs/sites complain that true tone causes flickering.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running Monterey.  The problem was that I had an HDMI cable plugged in. My iMac was changing resolutions.  The solution was to unplug the cable.