# Dual screen bug on mac Big Sur

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

On my MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020) with macOS Big Sur 11.4, my second screen works fine for approximately 2 hours. After those 2 hours, it turns off each 4-5 minutes for a few seconds.

I tried to change HDMI, change TnB hub, uncheck "True Tone" as mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421958/macbook-big-sur-screen-flickering-briefly-goes-black-then-returns-to-normal#comment595178_421958) to no avail.

I have tested 2 screens (Lenovo L27i-28 and iiyame 23.8").

This happened only with my MacBook Pro on Big Sur.

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT :**

I note that it happends during periods of high outdoor temperatures (35° C, 95° F) because when i place an electric fan in my desk near my MacBook it works fine.

My thunderbolt port is 48-49° C (120° F) and connected with hub.

Have any of you already had this problem ?

Comment: Same cable? Try a different HDMI cable, also if you have the option try a Thunderbolt, displayport or any other connection offered on the monitor as I have heard that HDMI can be problematic in some situations.

Comment: You asked a second question about the same problem. Please don't do this, instead modify your first question with the new details.